# Google apps script - Calendar Event - sendInvites by mail to myself

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a script which create an event in my calendar automatically and send an invitation to specified addresses. That works well when I specify address different from the email linked to my calendar.

But in my case I have 2 calendars so I would like to :
- Create the event in the calendar A
- Send an invitation by email, which creates at the same time the event (but not validated) in calendar B. 
- This way I can choose in the calendar B to decline or not the event

To do that I just have to send the invitation to my mail address (mymail@gmail.com). That almost works :
- The event is shown in calendar B and I can choose to decline it.
- BUT I don't receive any email for the invitation. It seems that send the invitation from a an address to the same address doesn't work.

Do you know why ? And is there a way to force the sent ?

```
var event = cal.createEvent(titre, DateDebut, DateFin, {description : description, guests : "mymail@gmail.com", sendInvites: true});
event.setGuestsCanModify(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the email is being sent by the calendar, the other way to force an email would be using the class `MailApp`  which allows you to send emails. This option allows you to make a custom email and invitation, and If I'm remembering correct allows you to send invites to non-google accounts.

Comment: The problem is not to send invitation to non-google account.

When I create my event in the calendar and activate invitations, the mail is sent from the gmail account linked to the calendar. And I want to send the invitation to this same address (=sending an email from an e-mail to the same e-mail).

Ans it seems this option sendInvites is not for this kind of situation which is weird I know

Comment: I  noticed some unpredictable behavior of this option "sendInvites:true". Sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't. Checked my mailQuota, and have left enough quota. Cannot find any clue to the solution.

Comment: Oops.. very valuable apparent reason: if date used is in the past, CalendarApp will not send invites.